# The maximum value of $f(x)$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, optimization, maxima-minima

$f(x)$ is twice differentiable function such that $f(x)+f''(x)=-x\big|sinx\big|f'(x)$ where $x\geq0.$Given that $f(0)=-3,f'(0)=4$ the maximum value of $f(x)$ is$?$

My Try:To say, I was never taught these second order DE's but this question appeared under the topic maxima-minima,however I am familiar with first order DE's.Any particular way to solve these type of questions(I mean second order DE's)$?$

Comment: What was the general topic around this task? One could find a numerical solution, follow a perturbation approach,...

Comment: @LutzLehmann how should I start this,I didn't get any ideas

Comment: I'm kind of thinking this one is the result of a typo, at least in light of the answer below which plots a solution.

Comment: Oof, I don't even expect a closed form here now. What is the source of this question? I'd love to believe there is a typo somewhere, I've not been shocked in some time so seeing that it is correct will give me one hopefully.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon this one is from lakshya book for JEE by career point

Comment: @TeresaLisbon also,there is no typo from my side

Comment: @IITM That's quite amazing, I think I have had enough of a shock! Are options given?

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Yes,options are given,they are...$3,4,5$ and does not exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ff'+f'f''=-x|\sin x|(f'(x))^2$$
$$d(f^2+(f')^2) \leq 0$$
can you continue after this

Comment: oh,thank you @Lakshman Singamsetty

Comment: @RicardoCavalcanti the last step means that the function $(f^2+(f')^2)$ is decreasing so,$(f^2+(f')^2) \leq f(0)^2+f'(0)^2$

Answer (score 0):

Maxima occur when $f'(x) = 0$, $f'(x)$ fails to exist, or at endpoints.

The domain has one endpoint, at $0$, but because $f'(0) = 4$, we can conclude that it is a local minimum and definitely not the maximum.

Since they say $f(x)$ is twice differentiable, $f'(x)$ must exist everywhere.

That leaves the final option, $f'(x) = 0$.  Plugging that in, the right hand side disappears and you are left with a much simpler equation. However, as @LutzLehmann pointed out, that equation only holds at the maxima themselves.

If it were not for that factor of $x$ I would pursue showing that $f(x)$ must be periodic.  Since it is there, that approach fails.

General ideas:
Look for traits the function must possess.  Is it always increasing?  (Then it would not attain a maximum, though it might approach one.)
$f''(0) = 3$ when you plug in the initial conditions.
Try restrictions.  Suppose $f''(x)$ is always positive?  Bounded?
Can you factor the unknown function?  Write $f(x) = g(x)\cdot e^x$, or other trial functions.
And of course, there is always numerical approximation as the fallback.
You can get a rough feel for the look of the equation via Euler's method.

Derivatives are a science, integrals are an art, and differential equations are a black art.  Good luck.

Comment: That much simpler equation is only valid at isolated points, where $f'(x)=0$.

Comment: Yes, and those are the points we are looking for. But I take your point.  I will edit.

Comment: @LutzLehmann That simple equation is also valid when $sinx=0? $,also RobertTheTutor I did not understand what you were trying to say..

Comment: Formulas have to match over intervals, not just at points, to be the same function for purposes of solving a differential equation.  $y = x+2$ and $y = x^2$ both pass through $(2,4)$ but that doesn't mean they have the same slope, for example.

Comment: Any other ideas or how to start off? Still stuck with this problem

Comment: Or may be give some process so I could continue

Answer (score 0):

To have any solution at all, consider the numerical solution. Use an event mechanism to find the roots of the derivative. Here in python, one could do almost literally the same in matlab/octave

```
def ode(x,f): return [f[1], -f[0]-x*abs(np.sin(x))*f[1]]
def evt(x,f): return f[1]
evt.direction=-1

sol = solve_ivp(ode,[0,10],[-3,4], events=evt, atol=1e-8, rtol=1e-9)

print(sol.t_events[0])
print(sol.y_events[0][:,0])
```

This gives exactly one event, there are no other extrema

```
x    = [1.8246435]
f(x) = [2.7319696]
```

The plot makes it clear that in the second $\pi$ interval the friction coefficient $x|\sin x|$ becomes so large that the oscillator is over-dampened, the solution falls directly to the asymptote $y=0$.

[image]